# Convert missing values to character strings

Tags: r, vector

Suppose I have the following test cases:

```
test1 <- c(rep("apple",1),rep("banana",3),rep("cat",1),rep(NA_character_,4),rep("dog",3),rep(NA_character_,2),rep("other",3))

test1
 [1] "apple"     "banana"    "banana"    "banana"    "cat"       NA          NA          NA         
 [9] NA          "dog"       "dog"       "dog"       NA          NA          "something" "something"
[17] "something"

test2 <- c(rep("setosa",4),rep("versicolor",4),rep(NA_character_,4),rep("virginica",3))
```

My goal is to convert first batch of missing values to "name1", second batch of missing values to "name2". etc.

Here are the desired outputs:

```
out1 <- c(rep("apple",1),rep("banana",3),rep("cat",1),rep("name1",4),rep("dog",3),rep("name2",2),rep("other",3))

out1
 [1] "apple"  "banana" "banana" "banana" "cat"    "name1"  "name1"  "name1"  "name1"  "dog"    "dog"   
[12] "dog"    "name2"  "name2"  "other"  "other"  "other" 

out2 <- c(rep("setosa",4),rep("versicolor",4),rep("name1",4),rep("virginica",3))
```

How do I achieve this? I tried `na_index <- which(is.na(test1))` and then I am stuck.

Comment: look at `cgwtools::seqle`, as your 'na_iindex' is just right for this. There's likely a regex lookback for this also, but I head scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to Stefan's answer, using `data.table:rleid` and integer factor conversion, instead of calling `rleid` twice:

```
replace_na_runs <- function(x) {
  ix <- is.na(x)
  x[ ix ] <- paste0("name", as.integer(factor(data.table::rleid(x)[ ix ])))
  x
}

replace_na_runs(test1)
#  [1] "apple"  "banana" "banana" "banana" "cat"    "name1" 
#  [7] "name1"  "name1"  "name1"  "dog"    "dog"    "dog"   
# [13] "name2"  "name2"  "other"  "other"  "other" 
replace_na_runs(test2)
#  [1] "setosa"     "setosa"     "setosa"     "setosa"    
#  [5] "versicolor" "versicolor" "versicolor" "versicolor"
#  [9] "name1"      "name1"      "name1"      "name1"     
# [13] "virginica"  "virginica"  "virginica"
```

**Note:** see the benchmarks, calling `rleid` twice is faster for *dplyr* and *data.table*:

```
replace_na_runs_faster <- function(x) {
  ix <- is.na(x)
  x[ ix ] <- paste0("name", data.table::rleid(data.table::rleid(x)[ ix ]))
  x
  }
```

Comment: Nice. Was sure there is a simpler option to using `consecutive_id` a second time. But sometimes one forgets about the basics. :D

Comment: @stefan Don't know why OP changed their mind... I was glad to see you had the "accepted" checkmark, as I was suspecting, calling rleid twice is faster than integer factor conversion, see benchmark.

Comment: For me this is fine. (: Not sure what's the OPs issue with `consecutive_id`. Perhaps a package version issue. And thx for your effort with doing some benchmarks. Interesting results. Would have expected that integer conversion outperforms calling `consectuive_id` twice.

Answer (score 4):

One option would be to use `dplyr::consecutive_id` two times. The first identifies the runs of missing values. While the second is used to assign the right id:

```r
library(dplyr, warn=FALSE)

replace_na_runs <- function(x) {
  x[is.na(x)] <- paste0(
    "name",
    consecutive_id(
      consecutive_id(is.na(x))[is.na(x)]
    )
  )
  x
}

replace_na_runs(test1)
#>  [1] "apple"  "banana" "banana" "banana" "cat"    "name1"  "name1"  "name1" 
#>  [9] "name1"  "dog"    "dog"    "dog"    "name2"  "name2"  "other"  "other" 
#> [17] "other"
replace_na_runs(test2)
#>  [1] "setosa"     "setosa"     "setosa"     "setosa"     "versicolor"
#>  [6] "versicolor" "versicolor" "versicolor" "name1"      "name1"     
#> [11] "name1"      "name1"      "virginica"  "virginica"  "virginica"
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Benchmark

Functions

```
dplyr1 <- function(x) {
  x[is.na(x)] <- paste0(
    "name",
    dplyr::consecutive_id(dplyr::consecutive_id(is.na(x))[is.na(x)]))
  x
}
dplyr2 <- function(x) {
  x[is.na(x)] <- paste0(
    "name",
    as.integer(as.factor(dplyr::consecutive_id(is.na(x))[is.na(x)])))
  x
}
dt1 <- function(x) {
  ix <- is.na(x)
  x[ ix ] <- paste0("name", data.table::rleid(data.table::rleid(x)[ ix ]))
  x
}
dt2 <- function(x) {
  ix <- is.na(x)
  x[ ix ] <- paste0("name", as.integer(factor(data.table::rleid(x)[ ix ])))
  x
}
```

Microbenchmark

```
mb <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  dplyr1(testbig),
  dplyr2(testbig),
  dt1(testbig),
  dt2(testbig),
  unit = "relative",
  check = "identical", 
  setup = {
    set.seed(1)
    testbig <- sample(c(LETTERS, NA), 1000000, replace = TRUE)
    })
```

Output

```
mb
#Unit: relative
#            expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
# dplyr1(testbig) 1.236691 1.248386 1.373232 1.231310 1.251993 4.318416   100
# dplyr2(testbig) 1.746286 1.757374 1.755433 1.746094 1.858594 1.335415   100
#    dt1(testbig) 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000   100
#    dt2(testbig) 1.990341 1.973550 1.917643 1.980112 2.006979 1.488243   100

ggplot2::autoplot(mb)
```

[image]